# compared two parameters using "<" in shell

Tags: linux, shell

let's assign like this:

```
a=7
b=29
[[ $a < $b ]] && echo dasf
```

it doesn't work!!

however, when

```
a=1
```

with b and command same, it works well.

That's very funky! Can somebody explain that?

Comment: In "shell", you have a syntax error.  The syntax you are using is valid in bash, but not in a generic shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing the variables lexically, not numerically.

Try

```
[[ $a -lt $b ]] && echo smaller
```

or

```
(( $a < $b )) && echo smaller
```